# How to Use Split in perl with regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I want to Split the Content from a number followed by .

```
my $info = "8. 9         Run
       Keywords :- RUN;

    9. 10        spreadsheet
       Keywords :- spreadsheet;

   10. 11        Book
       Keywords :- Book;

   11. 15        Hide
       Keywords :- Hide;

   12. 132        Pick
       Keywords :- Pick;
```

This the string that i have split the content according to the numbers like 8., 9., 10., 11.,12. 
Any suggestion how to do this in Perl and make sure that numbers like 8. does't appear after spiting.

Comment: `my @captures = $info =~ m/^\s*(\d+\.)/mg;`

Comment: I am not sure -- do you wan to split _by_ `8.` (etc)?  In other words, do you want to have `9 ... Run` (etc) in the end, OR, `8. 9. ...` (etc)?

Comment: What have you tried?  These posts lately have low scores and no demonstrated effort on execution.  There are language docs that show you how to implement the language, this seems more like trying to get someone to do your work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the objective is to split *by* `8.`, `9.` (etc)

```
my @contents = grep { /./ } split /\d+\./, $info;
```

The array `@contents` has `9   Run ...`(up to 9.), etc, with newlines and all.  The pattern `/.../` in [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is a full regular expression, which when matched in the string is taken to be a separator to split by. The regex above specifies a number followed by a period, so the string is split by any such.

Since `split` in this case also captures (the empty string) *before* the first match (`8.`), we use [grep](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to filter out empty strings, by requiring that each element matches at least one character.

You may also want to opt  for more substantial filtering, like with `grep { /\S/ }`, which would require that each element has at least one non-space thus discarding those which have only spaces.

Or, you can check only the first element

```
my @contents = split /\d+\./, $info;
shift @contents if $contents[0] eq '';
```

In the shown example there surely will be an empty string first.

What the most suitable approach is in general depends on what may actually be before `8.`, what you want to do with it, and what you want to do with possible elements containing only spaces (like from `14.  15.`), or even empty strings (from `14.15.`).

---

If the objective was to *capture* `8.`, `9.` (etc) then regex is better

```
my @num_dot = $info =~ /(\d+\.)/g;
```

The array `@num_dot` contains: `8. 9. 10. 11. 12.`

Answer (score 2):

It's not quite clear what you want, but splitting on the numbers seems like a poor approach to accomplishing anything.

At the very least, you want to make per-record changes and/or extract per-record information, so it would be far better to split the data into records. Each record is separated by a blank line, so we can use

```
my @items = split /\n\n/, $info;
```

This gives:

```
my @items = (
   "8. 9         Run\n       Keywords :- RUN;",
   "    9. 10        spreadshee\n       Keywords :- spreadsheet;",
   "   10. 11        Book\n       Keywords :- Book;",
   "   11. 15        Hide\n       Keywords :- Hide;",
   "   12. 132        Pick\n       Keywords :- Pick;",
);
```

Now, it seems you want to remove the numbers.

```
s/^\s*\K\d+\.\s*// for @items;   # Preserves the leading whitespace.

s/^\s*\d+\.\s*// for @items;     # Removes the leading whitespace.
```

The latter gives:

```
my @items = (
   "9         Run\n       Keywords :- RUN;",
   "10        spreadshee\n       Keywords :- spreadsheet;",
   "11        Book\n       Keywords :- Book;",
   "15        Hide\n       Keywords :- Hide;",
   "132        Pick\n       Keywords :- Pick;",
);
```

You could reconstruct `$info` minus the numbers by using

```
$info = join("\n\n", @items);
```

This gives:

```
9         Run
       Keywords :- RUN;

10        spreadshee
       Keywords :- spreadsheet;

11        Book
       Keywords :- Book;

15        Hide
       Keywords :- Hide;

132        Pick
       Keywords :- Pick;
```

If this doesn't answer your question, but clarify what output you expect from your example.